# isset() is returning only true

Tags: php, validation, isset

I am trying to create validations in PHP to check if fields are empty or not.

But my isset's are returning only true when I'm using

```
var_dump(isset($_POST['name']));
```

It's not returning false in any conditions which is not validating my forms properly.

Comment: u may try to use `isempty()` this might solve ur problem

Comment: Does `isset` return true for all `$_POST` variables, or just one? Does it return true everywhere in your code?

Comment: `isset()` will return true if `$_POST['name']` exists even if its empty... are you sure you don't send a data named `name` ?

Comment: You should probably use `isset($_POST['name']) && strlen($_POST['name']))` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP has different functions which can be used to test the value of a variable. Three useful functions for this are **isset(), empty() and is_null()**. All these function return a boolean value. If these functions are not used in correct way they can cause unexpected results.

isset() and empty() are often viewed as functions that are opposite, however this is not always true. In this post I will explain the differences between these functions.

```
isset()
```

> isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

In other words, it returns **true** only when the variable is **not null**.

```
empty()
```

> empty — Determine whether a variable is empty

In other words, it will return **true** if the variable is an empty string, false, array(), NULL, “0?, 0, and an unset variable.

```
is_null()
```

> is_null — Finds whether a variable is NULL

In other words, it returns **true** only when the variable is **null**. is_null() is opposite of isset(), except for one difference that isset() can be applied to unknown variables, but is_null() only to declared variables.

Comment: Always a pleasure @harsimarriar96 :)

Answer (score 4):

An empty string is a set string. It's not the same, you also have to check the length of the string or if it is empty or not

Comment: Optimally, `if( empty($_POST['name']))` will combine the work of `if( isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'])`